# Multilevel dependency injection in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have 5 classes as shown below. The execution starts at class 5. Here dependency injection is being used as the listener object is passed to the constructor of the `Bot` class and then that object calls listen() method. This part is fine.

The trouble starts from now on.

From the `listen()` method I call another method called `process()` which is in the `Processor` class (`processor.py` file). Then the `process()` method calls two other methods from 2 different classes `Tokenizer` and `Core`.

As you can see all these are coupled and dependency injection is not used here. I'm not sure how to.

I have tried out examples of python `dependency-injector` package and `pinject` package but those examples relate with single level dependencies and not cases like this as far as I can understand.

I have thought of creating all required objects in one module and passing it as parameters to all classes when required. But that doesn't seem like a good practice.

What can I do to decouple the above code? How should I go about modularizing this?

```
# core.py

class Core:
    def decide(self, data):
        """ Makes decisions based on input data """

        # blah blah
```

-

```
# tokenizer.py

import nltk

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english'))

class Tokenizer:
    def tokenize(self, query):
        """ Tokenize the input query string """
        tokenized_query = word_tokenize(query)
        clean_query = [w for w in tokenized_query if not w in stoplist]
        return clean_query
```

-

```
# processor.py

import tokenizer
import core

class Processor:
    def process(self, query):
        """ 
        Send the input query to tokenizer 
        tokenized input is send to the Core module for decision making
        """
        tokenized_input = tokenizer.Tokenizer().tokenize(query)
        core.Core().decide(tokenized_input)
```

-

```
# listener.py

import processor

class Listener:
    def listen(self):
        """ Continuosly listens to user input """
        while True:
            query=input()
            processor.Processor().process(query)
```

-

```
# bot.py

import listener

class Bot:
    def __init__(self, listener):
        listener.listen()

Bot(listener.Listener())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the utility classes class attributes:

```
class Core:
    def decide(self, data):
        return False


class Tokenizer:
    def tokenize(self, query):
        return []  # ...


class Processor:
    tokenizer_class = Tokenizer
    core_class = Core

    def process(self, query):
        tokenized_input = self.tokenizer_class().tokenize(query)
        return self.core_class().decide(tokenized_input)


class Listener:
    processor_class = Processor

    def listen(self):
        while True:
            query = input()
            self.processor_class().process(query)
```

You can then use your test framework's mock/patch features, e.g. pytest's `monkeypatch`:

```
def test_foo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(Processor, 'tokenizer_class', FooTokenizer)
    # etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can rethinking this design having in mind two concepts:

1. Python Multiple Inheritance to design your classes.
2. Usage of super() and Python's Method Resolution Order (MRO) to inject mocks for classes' dependencies within test code.

Regarding the first point, your classes will look like:

```
# core.py

class Core:
    def decide(self, data):
        """ Makes decisions based on input data """

        # blah blah

# tokenizer.py

class Tokenizer:
    def tokenize(self, query):
        """ Tokenize the input query string """
        return query

# processor.py
# from tokenizer import Tokenizer
# from core import Core

class Processor(Core, Tokenizer):
    def process(self, query):
        """ 
        Send the input query to tokenizer 
        tokenized input is send to the Core module for decision making
        """
        tokenized_input = super().tokenize(query)
        super().decide(tokenized_input)

# listener.py
# from processor import Processor

class Listener(Processor):
    def listen(self):
        """ Continuosly listens to user input """
        while True:
            query=input()
            super().process(query)

# bot.py
#from listener import Listener

class Bot(Listener):
    def start_listener(self):
        super().listen()


Bot().start_listener()
```

With this OO design and the usage of **super()**, we can take advantage of the MRO to inject mocks in our classes' dependencies, i'm going to show how to inject mocks in our SUT (subject under test) for its dependencies.

Examples for **Bot** and **Processor**:

```
class MockCore(Core):
    def decide(self, data):
        """ Here you can implement the behavior of the mock """

class MockTokenizer(Tokenizer):
    def tokenize(self, query):
        """ Here you can implement the behavior of the mock """
        return query

class ProcessorSut(Processor, MockCore, MockTokenizer):
    'Here we are injecting mocks for Processor dependencies'

class Bot(Listener):
    def start_listener(self):
        super().listen()

class MockListener(Listener):
    def listen(self):
        """ Here you can implement the behavior of the mock """
        return

class BotSut(Bot, MockListener):
    'Here we are injecting a mock for the Listener dependency of Bot'
```

Seeing the MRO of our SUT classes we can understand why the Multiple Inheritance and the usage of super() allow us to inject mocks in this way.

Resulting MRO for **BotSut** and **ProcessorSut**:

```
Help on class BotSut in module __main__:

class BotSut(Bot, MockListener)
 |  Here we are injecting a mock for the Listener dependency of Bot
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      BotSut
 |      Bot
 |      MockListener
 |      Listener
 |      Processor
 |      Core
 |      Tokenizer
 |      builtins.object
...
...
Help on class ProcessorSut in module __main__:

class ProcessorSut(Processor, MockCore, MockTokenizer)
 |  Here we are injecting mocks for Processor dependencies
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      ProcessorSut
 |      Processor
 |      MockCore
 |      Core
 |      MockTokenizer
 |      Tokenizer
 |      builtins.object
```

For more information:

- https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo&t=1351s
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html

Comment: Have in mind that you have the nltk dependency in your Tokenizer class, for this, i would suggest to wrap the dependency in a new class that just use the nltk dependency but add no logic. With this you are going to be able to isolate the Tokenizer class from its nltk dependency in your tests